# Gitlab CI pipeline status monitoring

Tags: linux, open-source, monitoring, continuous-integration, gitlab

I'm looking for a desktop application that monitors Gitlab CI pipelines and shows desktop notifications when they succeed or fail.
Gitlab CI's browser notifications are very unreliable, so a separate Linux desktop app would be nice.
Open Source preferred.

I know of CatLight, but it's a Electron app that takes nearly 400 MiB disk space, and you get "faster notifications" if you pay them, which means that the non-paid version slows down notifications deliberately.